# mkdir not working in npm script on linux, but works on mac

Tags: node.js, linux, bash, ubuntu, npm

I have a `"prebuild"` script that does the following:

```
mkdir -p dist/{server,shared,client/{css,js,fonts,img}}
```

I'd like for this to create a structure like so:

```
dist
    server
    shared
    client
        css
        js
        fonts
        img
```

When I run the `mkdir` command right from the terminal, it has the right output. However, if I put this command as an npm script like so:

**package.json**

```
{
    "scripts": {
        "prebuild": "mkdir -p dist/{server,shared,client/{css,js,fonts,img}}"
    }
}
```

And then when I do `npm run prebuild`, it only creates a single folder with a weird name: `{server,shared,client`.

So on Ubuntu, it only works when you type the command directly, but if you put it in an npm script you get this issue. On Mac, it works either way.

Does anyone know why this is happening?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`npm` uses `/bin/sh` to execute scripts, but Ubuntu uses `dash` as its POSIX shell, while Mac OS X uses `bash`. Brace expansion is a `bash` feature, which `dash` does not have.

`bash` (incorrectly, I would argue) still processes brace expansion when invoked as `sh`.

Comment: Done, sorry forgot to do it after having to wait 15 mins

Answer (score 0):

Great explanation from chepner.  I have added to the answer to give a solution.  Creating a link to the bash shell will allow you to run bash commands from the npm scripts.

```
$ sudo ln -sf bash /bin/sh
```

Hope this helps others running into this issue in Ubuntu.

[Credit to the link solution.](https://github.com/apex/apex/issues/589)